PWA SW Worked checkForUpdate Never Resolves
I have been trying to work with the PWA for our application to ensure that it updates as necessary but for some reason neither the checkForUpdate nor versionUpdates methods resolve to any values.
  constructor(
    appRef: ApplicationRef,
    updates: SwUpdate,
  ) {
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      const appIsStable$ = appRef.isStable
        .pipe(first(isStable => isStable === true));
      const everyMinute$ = interval(60 * 1000);
      const everyMinuteOnceAppIsStable$ = concat(appIsStable$, everyMinute$);

      const checkForUpdatesSub = everyMinuteOnceAppIsStable$
        .subscribe({
          next: async updateFound => {
            const update = await updates.checkForUpdate(); // My code reaches this point.
            console.log(update); // However, my code never reaches this point.
          }
        });
    }
  }

I thought maybe it didn't like being converted to an observable so, I have also attempted using both await and .then; Neither worked.
constructor(
    appRef: ApplicationRef,
    updates: SwUpdate,
  ) {
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      ...
      const checkForUpdatesSub = everyMinuteOnceAppIsStable$
        .pipe(
          tap(void (async(_) => {
            const hasUpdate: boolean = await updates.checkForUpdate();
            console.log(hasUpdate);
          })
        )
        .subscribe()
    }
  }

and
constructor(
    appRef: ApplicationRef,
    updates: SwUpdate,
  ) {
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      ...
      const checkForUpdatesSub = everyMinuteOnceAppIsStable$
        .pipe(
          tap((_) => {
            updates.checkForUpdate().then((hasUpdate) => {
              console.log(hasUpdate);
            })
          })
        )
        .subscribe()
    }
  }

and
constructor(
    appRef: ApplicationRef,
    updates: SwUpdate,
  ) {
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      ...
      const checkForUpdatesSub = everyMinuteOnceAppIsStable$
        .subscribe({
          next: _ => {
            updates.checkForUpdate().then((hasUpdate) => {
              console.log(hasUpdate);
            })
          }
        });
    }
  }


Maybe subscribe does not support async await instead go for .then( to wait for the promise to resolve and finally call the console.log!
...
.subscribe({
      next: updateFound => {
        updates.checkForUpdate().then((update: any) => {
            console.log(update); // However, my code never reaches this point.
        });
      }
    });
    ...


Sorry, I forgot to include the other variations I've attempted which include both await and .then. I've updated the question to include these.
